# como crear una tabla a partir de datos ingresados en formulario en un popup en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

tengo un formulario en un index.html, este formulario contiene información de material que se da de baja, en una columna de este formulario hay un botón agregar, el cual levanta un popup con otro formulario que es el detalle de lo que se dara de baja (item, cantidad, contenido, descripción), en este popup al terminar de llenar los datos solicitados, hay un botón que dice agregar.
cuando se presiona el botón agregar, los datos ingresados se tienen que ingresar en una tabla que se crea en el momento que se apreta el botón.

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Bwl.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo en javascript

```
$("#AgrDescripcion").click(function() {
    $("#cant").val("");
    $("#uMedida").val("");
    $("#txtDescripcionActividad").val("");
    $("#condicion").val(""); 
    $("#AC").val("");

    $("#modalIngresaDescripcion").dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
    },
        title: "Prueba",
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        resizable: false,
        height:200,
        width:850,
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
            "Aceptar": function(){
                var params={};
                params.cant=$('#cant').val();
                params.uMedida=$('#uMedida').val();
                params.descrip=$('#txtDescripcionActividad').val();
                params.condi=$('#condicion').val();
                params.aFijo=$('#AC').val();

                console.log(params);

                var n = $('tr:last td', $("#addTable")).length;
                var tds = '<tr>';
                for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
                  tds += '<td>nuevo</td>';
                }
                tds += '</tr>';
                $("#addTable").append(tds);
            },
            "Salir": function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }       
    });

});
```

y esta es la tabla que se llena

```
<div id="agregaTabla">
        <table id="addTable">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

el tema ahora, es que no se como pasar los parámetros, solo me muestra 'nuevo'

Comment: Hola elsa, bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español. Desafortunadamente, esta comunidad no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que te invito a modifiques tu pregunta para que se ajuste a las normas de calidad del sitio. Para hacer más fácil del proceso, te recomiendo que sigas [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jasilva modifique un poco la pregunta, pero no es mas que eso no se como explicarlo de otra forma

Comment: modifique mas la pregunta y adjunte img por si entienden mejor :) @jasilva

Comment: agregue el código en la pregunta @jasilva

Comment: Agregue una respuesta, espero te sirva, para la proxima vez, intenta colocar el codigo actual que tienes, asi como unas explicacion mas detallada de lo que quieres obtener, asi recibiras mejores respuestas desde un inicio :) Procedo a borrar mis otros comentarios para limpieza de la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes sustituir el ciclo que agregas las table-data (`td`) por este codigo

```
            /*for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
              tds += '<td>nuevo</td>';
            }*/
            tds += '<td>' + params.cant + '</td>';
            tds += '<td>' + params.uMedida + '</td>';
            tds += '<td>' + params.descrip + '</td>';
            tds += '<td>' + params.condi + '</td>';
            tds += '<td>' + params.aFijo + '</td>';

            tds += '</tr>';
```

Donde simplemente ponemos los parametros que ya capturaste antes

---

Concatenar codigo html para despues agregarlo al dom no simpre es la mejor opción, sobretodo cuando se tiene que agregar mas propiedas a cada elemento.

Podemos hacerlo creando objetos jQuery.

Como muestro a continuación:

```
            var trow = $('<tr/>', {
                class : 'alguna-clase'
            }).appendTo('#addTable');

            $('<td/>',{                    
                text: params.cant
            }).appendTo(trow);
            $('<td/>',{                   
                text: params.uMedida
            }).appendTo(trow);
            $('<td/>',{                    
                text: params.descrip
            }).appendTo(trow);
            $('<td/>',{                   
                text: params.condi
            }).appendTo(trow);
            $('<td/>',{                    
                text: params.aFijo
            }).appendTo(trow);
```

Puedes ver este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5h5pf99/) para ver como funciona, donde he comentado las otras partes que no se usarian